# React App - Div is centered on local host but not when deployed to github pages

Tags: html, css, reactjs, github, github-pages

I have an issue with my create-react-app being deployed on github pages.

In this first picture, it's my deployed app on github pages. The image is supposed to be centered in the middle of the page.

[image: Deployed]

This second picture shows what it looks like when ran on my localhost with npm start.

[image]

Here's the code, if anyone could help me figure out how to make the image centered in the deploy, that would be awesome thanks:

In my About.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import me from '../../photos/portraits/portraits8.jpg';
import './About.css';


const About = () =>  {
  return(
    <div>
    <figure className="figure center">
      <img src={me} alt="" className="about-img"/>
      <figcaption className="figcaption bg-color">Hi, my name is Thomas Nguyen, and I’m a freelance photographer based in Morgan Hill, CA. My main focus is automotive photography as well as portrait photography. I'm also a Software Engineer, and this whole website was built with React, Javascript, CSS, and HTML!</figcaption>
    </figure>
    </div>
  );
}


export default About;
```

In my About.css:

```
.about-img{
  /*max-height: 500px;*/
  max-height: 400px;
  height: auto\9;
  width: auto;
}

.center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}


.figure {
  display: table;
  margin: 0;
}

.figcaption {
  display: table-caption;
  caption-side: bottom;
  padding: 10px;
}

.bg-color{
  background-color: rgba(78, 100, 124, .1);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only mystery is how it works in local environment in the first place. Once I copied the code to a brand new HTML file, it didn't work. All styles written in `.center` class were not applied by the browser, so no content was centered. The reason for this is that you can't apply margins on `display: table` element. If you check your classes, you'll see that `.figure` class overrides `display: block` property of `.center` class.

Therefore, do it like this:

```
<style>
.center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
</style>

<div className="center">
    <figure className="figure">
      ...rest of the code
    </figure>
</div>
```

So, remove `.center` class from figure tag, and place it on wrapping `div`. Then change CSS properties of `.center` class so it can center the figure properly.

Comment: Hmm, that really is quite weird. Not sure why it worked in my localhost. Thank you! This worked perfectly.